# change state of gridview in android onActivityResult

Tags: android

i m developing guessing the game app,my question is, i have created grid view in which user selects one image and enters its name if that is correct then it has to store its state to file as true and that particular image in grid view state has to be changed how to do this....

1st java file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.andy);

    gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mImgs));


    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            //String name=getResources().getResourceEntryName(mImgs[arg2]);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Bundle basket=new Bundle();
            Intent i=new Intent(Andy.this,AndyImg.class);
            basket.putString("hintName", hintName[arg2]);
            basket.putString("solvedName", solvedName[arg2]);                   
            i.putExtra("index",arg2);
            i.putExtra("lvl", 1);
            i.putExtras(basket);

            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }

    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        //Bundle b=data.getExtras();
        //int i=b.getInt("int");
        //int c=gv.getCount();



    }
}
}
```

2nd java file:

```
 public class AndyImg extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button check;
TextView textv, solvedDisplay, coins, hintClick, solvedClick;
EditText et;
ImageView iv, ad;
Bundle basket;
int indexOfImg, level;
String hintName, solvedName;
AlertDialog alert;
int val = 1,coi;
LinearLayout ll;

SharedPreferences coinData, levelStatus,savedLevel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fullScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.andyimg);

    intializevars();
    getDataFromPrev();
    checkState();

    hintClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    solvedClick.setOnClickListener(this);
    check.setOnClickListener(this);
    solvedDisplay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void intializevars() {
    textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaygame);
    // hintDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hint);
    solvedDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solvedText);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editgame);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.masterImg);

    hintClick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hinttv);
    solvedClick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solvedtv);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkgame);
    coins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coins);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin1);
}

public void getDataFromPrev() {
    basket = getIntent().getExtras();
    indexOfImg = basket.getInt("index");// get index of selected image
    hintName = basket.getString("hintName");// get hint from andy
    solvedName = basket.getString("solvedName");// get fully solved name
    // Bitmap img=(Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("img");
    level = basket.getInt("lvl");
    switch (level) {
    case 1:
        iv.setImageResource(Andy.mImgs[indexOfImg]);// set Selected image to
                                // the image view
        break;

    case 2:
        iv.setImageResource(AndyLevelTwo.mImgs[indexOfImg]);

        break;
    case 3:
        iv.setImageResource(AndyLevelThree.mImgs[indexOfImg]);
        break;
    }
}

public void checkState() {

}

public void fullScreen() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {


    case R.id.checkgame:
                        // check button
        String editTxt = et.getText().toString();
        solvedName = solvedName.replace(" ", "");
        editTxt = editTxt.replace(" ", "");// remove spaces and compare
        if (editTxt.compareToIgnoreCase(solvedName) == 0) {

            textv.setText("Correct ");
            textv.append(solvedName);
            //Intent i = new Intent();  i thought to do it onActivityResult is this correct?or is there any better sol
            //i.putExtra("int", indexOfImg);
            //setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

            finish();

            // hintClick.setEnabled(false);
            //ll.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            textv.setText("incorrect");
            textv.append(editTxt);

            // textv.setText(level);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think setting the result using `setResult()` in 2nd `Activity` will be the better way.

Comment: tried that but i dont know how to change particular image in gridview